# Enterprise Library Logging and Alert E-mails

Tags: .net, logging, enterprise-library

Is it possible to set up the Enterprise Library to only send alert e-mails for certain types of events where the "type of event" can change without recompiling the entire program or having to edit a .config file?

In a perfect world, I'd be able to toggle a setting in SQL Server to say "by default, e-mail a@example.com. For sources that meet a certain criteria, e-mail b@example.com. And, for some other criteria, e-mail c@example.com".

More generally, I'm looking for a logging framework that will let me say "for sources 1 2 and 3, spam everyone if something dies but for #4, just e-mail 1 person". The source is set by a number inside each file being processed by the application (although I plan to set things up so that 1 thread only works on 1 source so that's an option too).

I see that Nlog and Log4Net are also popular but I haven't investigated them as deeply yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an email listener [email trace listener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664760%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx).  Below is an example of one from enterprise library 3.1

```
      <add toAddress="to@mail.com" fromAddress="from@mail.com"
    subjectLineStarter="Load" subjectLineEnder="" smtpServer="mailserver.com"
    smtpPort="25" formatter="Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.EmailTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    traceOutputOptions="None" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.EmailTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    name="Email TraceListener" />
```

Then you'll need to add specialsources

```
    <specialSources>
  <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Email TraceListener" />
    </listeners>
  </allEvents>
  <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
  <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings" />
</specialSources>
```